# Database architecture for interactions between users (8B rows, 1TB of data)

Tags: mysql, database-design, nosql, architecture

I'm saving an interactions table between two users. I have two interaction types, and each interaction can happen more than once. The easiest reference would be Facebook Likes and comments on posts: `User1` did two likes, and 1 comment on `User2`.

I would also like basic query abilities, like all users that interacted with `User1`, and users `User1` has interacted with sorted by how many interactions.

I'm currently saving this in MySQL, and things have been going well, but as the table is getting big (7.5B rows, 1TB total disk space divided equally between data and indexes), INSERTS have become very slow. Can take up to a minute for 1k rows.

My Current Table Structure:

```
 CREATE TABLE `interactions` (
  `user_id_to` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id_from` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type2counter` tinyint(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `counter` smallint(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `updated` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id_to`,`user_id_from`),
  KEY `uid_from` (`user_id_from`),
  KEY `uid_to_counter` (`user_id_to`,`counter`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Edit: Insert look like this:

```
INSERT INTO interactions
     (user_id_to, user_id_from, counter, updated)
   VALUES 
     ('2266931634','3180832729','3',NOW() ), 
     ('2266931634','3133897242','1',NOW() ), 
     ('2266931634','3207247957','1',NOW() ),  
     ('2266931634','3520390476','1',NOW() ), 
     ('2266931634','3631954079','1',NOW() ), 
     ('2266931634','3687475949','1',NOW() ), 
     ('2266931634','3627629761','1',NOW() ), 
     ('2266931634','3779990751','1',NOW() ), 
     ('2266931634','4071753134','1',NOW() ), 
     ('2266931634','4290900946','3',NOW() ) 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
             counter=counter+VALUES(counter),
             updated=NOW()
```

MySQL version: 5.6.19

Answer (score 3):

Something wrong with that!  There is no column `counter`??

But, assuming you meant one of the existing counters...

- Having the `counter` in an index, *and* updating the counter frequently --> double the work.  Once to update the table, once to update the index.
- Since the *first* part of the `PRIMARY KEY` is `user_id_to`, you have a very good way of locating the `counter` given the `user_id_to`.  So, `DROP` that index.  This will speed things up considerably.

Something else to check...  `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be about 70% of RAM.  What are the value of those?

`PARTITIONing` is very unlikely to help.  Given a good index, partitioning is no faster because it is essentially turns a 1-step process (look up in the index) into a 2-step process: first find the partition ("pruning"), then use the index in that partition.

If possible, use either `LOAD DATA` or "batch" `INSERTs`.

What do the `INSERTs` look like?  Perhaps `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`?  For batching, that might be best done by creating a tmp table, then using IODKU with a SELECT on the tmp table.  [*More*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table) on high speed ingestion.

Some things look fishy, please provide specifics on the inserts, updates, and selects.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58903/discussion-on-answer-by-rick-james-database-architecture-for-interactions-betwee).